# How to trigger (possibly)overridden event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I created `jQuery UI Dialog` and after the dialog is displayed, wherever a user clicks, the dialog is closed. I achieved this by adding click event to the body tag.

```
$("body").click(function() {
   $("#myDialog").dialog("close").dialog("destroy");
});
```

It works fine except inside of `3rd party Grid API` I'm using and found out this Grid API source code, it defined onclick event like below:

```
this.obj.onclick = function(e){
    console.log("grid API clicked");
    this.grid._doClick(e||window.event);

    if (this.grid._sclE) {
        this.grid.editCell(e||window.event); 
    }

    (e||event).cancelBubble=true;
};
```

When I clicked inside the Grid, the log msg "grid API clicked" is shown in my firebug but my body click event is not triggered so I think the event is not bubbling up to the body click event as specified in the line `(e||event).cancelBubble=true;`

If I set this to `false`, the click on the Grid does not work and not wanting to change code in the 3rd party API.

So, it there any workaround to make body click work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simplistic and not the best way to do it, but if you're happy to edit the Grid API source then add this to it...

```
$("body").click();
```

It will trigger the click event defined on the body element.  If that doesn't work then there's something else going on.

Comment: I agree that is one way.. so as far as I know there isn't way to achieve my goal without modifying the Grid API..